# MySQL value constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

I've two entities named "prenotation" and "customer", linked by a relation named "made".
So, on MySQL, I've three tables: "prenotation", "customer" and "made".
On "made" there are two foreign keys (FK_prenotation, FK_customer).
Prenotation code always refers to a single customer.
On "prenotation" table I've to insert prenotation code and customer code, to whom that prenotation refers. For example, prenotation code = 2 refers to a customer, whose code = 14.

The problem is:
When I insert a row on "made" table, I can insert prenotation code = 2 that refers to any customer (for example, customer code = 18), but I want that prenotation code = 2 refers only to customer 14! How can I set this constraint?

Comment: If the prenotion only ever refers to one customer you dont need a link table, just store the key of the customer in the prenotion

Comment: I've two relations between "prenotation" and "customer": "made" and "make" (I can't delete one of them). I built the second one on the way that you suggested, but the first one requires what I wrote on the question.

Comment: So what does the other link table do

Comment: "Made" stores old prenotations, "Make" stores prenotations that are still running

Comment: Do you mean Promotions

Comment: *I've two relations between "prenotation" and "customer": "made" and "make"* If so then set `made.FK_customer` column as unique (create according unique index).

Comment: *"Made" stores old prenotations, "Make" stores prenotations that are still running* ??? this contradicts with "only one customer for the same prenotation", it seems. Or the prenotation which have already referred to some definite customer can be referred to only this customer forever, and referring to another customer after previous prenotation finished its running (there is no a row with this prenotation in "make") is impossible? Maybe you confuse "make" and "made" tables?

Comment: I'll use an example. I'm booking room n° 25 in a hotel (and my customer code is 90). Until I leave, the prenotation is running, so this prenotation will be stored on "prenotation" table (cause, for "customer make prenotation" I used foreign key way and not join table way).
Once I am gone, the prenotation becomes passed and then it will be stored on "made" table (cause, this time, I'm using join table).

Comment: Now on "made" table i'll write "prenotation code=25" and "customer code=90", but i can write any code I want on "customer code" if I don't create a constraint. What kind of constraint should I create to prevent me from entering any customer code?